# Any Cortex-M3(LPC1768) compilers for Linux?

Tags: linux, cortex-m, ide

Are there any uVision alternatives for Ubuntu/Linux?, i know about LPCxpresso, but i just don't like it and its only for LPC MCUs.

i tried Googling and it didn't help, I only saw results about LPCXpresso.

Comment: GCC compilers support the Cortex M series. You may need to do a bit of manipulation to get it compiling for LPC parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) is a cross-platform cross-compiler, used widely with ARM platforms (and dozens of others). Some pre-built toolchains can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) or built by yourself. If you are looking for an IDE, you can use [Eclipse](http://Eclipse) with plugins like [this](http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/).

Comment: Thanks! the coding is just like uVision? i just include <lpc17xx.h> and do the same stuff?!(and are registers the same? like GPIO2->FIOSET = 0xff);

Comment: The registers are not compiler specific, they are CPU/MCU specific, so yes, they are the same. For the other stuff I believe it would be quite different. The syntax can be a little different, and the whole setup I believe won't be so straightforward, so you gonna learn much new stuff. But the experience you will learn will serve you well if you migrate to different MCU families.

Comment: Where can i learn the diffrences and how to use it? i tried googling and got no result! (arm gcc toolchain cortex-m3)Edit: found this: http://wiki.dlang.org/Bare_Metal_ARM_Cortex-M_GDC_Cross_Compiler let me read it :)

Comment: You have a really strange Google, you know... For me it gives a plenty of results, most of them even useful. Check this one, for example. It is not a bes one, but it is talking about LPCxxx family: http://vedder.se/2012/04/setup_arm_toolchain/

Comment: can i know what you googled?

Comment: For this specific result I can't remember now. But generally "arm eclipse gcc" is a good start.